# How could I select particular data and reform my data structure? csv python

Tags: python, csv

I have a matrix.csv file which looks like this,

```
  1,2,3,4 ............
1,A,B,C,D
2,E,F,G,H
3,I,J,K,L
4,M,N,P,Q
.
.
.
.
```

However, I only need a subset of the data (Because B is just E^-1, C is I^-1 and so on, which I do not need all of them.)

```
  1,2,3,4 ........
1,A
2,E,F
3,I,J,K
4,M,N,P,Q
.
.
.
.
.
```

Then, I hope I can get a result.csv file looks like below,

```
1,1,A
2,1,E
2,2,F
3,1,I
3,2,J
3,3,K
4,1,M
4,2,N
4,3,P
4,4,Q
....
....
....
....
```

I have tried to find a solution for the entire day, but I still cannot get it to work. Does anyone know how to solve with this problem by using python?

Thanks,

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Run two nested loops: `i` for the row, `j <= i` for the column. Write result rows `i,j,input[i][j]`.

Comment: Your question sounds a bit abstract, and I'm guessing that `A`, `B`, etc actually represent some data (numbers?) in a matrix.  It might help if you explain what you are really trying to achieve, but I think that [http://pandas.pydata.org/](pandas) might be of use to you.

Comment: Sorry I am still a new hand to python, well at the beginning I used ginv() in R to deal with this problem, which I am still working on this, then I guess python might be helpful so I tried to use range() function to work this out. And thanks, I know pandas is a good option, however, I may need some times to check the documents. Much appreciated for your guys' advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  Basically I just read in the entire file into a 2D array, then iterate through the array with each row (i-loop) adding one more column (j-loop).

```
import csv, os
with open('in.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    a = []
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
        a += [ row ]

f = open('out.csv', 'w')
i = 0
for i in range(len(a[0])):
    i += 1
    for j in range(i):
        f.write(str(i) + "," + str(j+1) + "," + str(a[i][j+1]) + os.linesep)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for help, however, I saw something like this, do you have any ideas about this issue, much appreciated for your help, f.write(str(i) + "," + str(j+1) + "," + str(a[i][j+1]) + os.linesep)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: sorry about adding comment again, even it appears IndexError but I still got the correct result!

Comment: Has to do with the indices a[i][j+1]. One of them is out of bounds.  Maybe your input file that you are using is different than what you gave above?  I just tried with the sample above.

Comment: Hi @user3058889 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I'd like to do so whereas my reputation is not enough at this moment therefore I cannot up-vote your guys answer. I will supply vote again once I get sufficient reputation! :)

Comment: Understand... I have a similar problem.  But I don't mean upvoting, I mean accepting an answer by clicking the check mark as explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

A numpy solution as below. Basically all you want is to list out those values with axis_y >= axis_x:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np

datacsv = StringIO("""A,B,C,D
E,F,G,H
I,J,K,L
M,N,O,P
""")

data = np.genfromtxt(datacsv, dtype='S1', delimiter=',', skip_header=False)

ROW, COL = data.shape
assert (ROW == COL)

indexes = np.arange(ROW*COL)
y = indexes/ROW
x = np.mod(indexes, ROW)
v = data.reshape(ROW*COL)

a = np.column_stack((x, y, v))[y >= x]
np.savetxt('output.csv', a, fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```